# Stop NLS settings in init.ora getting overridden by environment variable

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, parameter

We have a databases server that is used for development which has hundreds of database instances for different branches/builds of our application. And we needed an special instance that has `NLS_CALENDAR='Thai Buddha'` to test a particular bug.

We have set up a database and included `NLS_CALENDAR='Thai Buddha'` setting in `init.ora`. However, we still get `'GREGORIAN'` for `NLS_CALENDAR`, since environment variables overrides the setting in `init.ora`.

`NLS_CALENDAR` value is set as follows:

`NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS: 'GREGORIAN'`

`NLS_INSTANCE_PARAMETERS: 'Thai Buddha'`

`NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS: 'GREGORIAN'`

`ALTER SESSION` is not an option because then we have to modify our application code to issue an `ALTER SESSION` whenever a user logs in (This is not possible because we have multiple clients already deployed on various machines). Modifying the environment setting is not an option either because there are other database instances running on the same host.

I have tried `ALTER SYSTEM`, but it gives following oracle error:

> ORA-02096: specified initialization parameter is not modifiable with this
>   option

How can we make a single database instance to ignore the environment setting? Or is there any other way we can make our instance default to `'Thai Buddha'` when it comes to `NLS_CALENDAR` setting?

Comment: What do you mean by "we still get 'GREGORIAN' for NLS_CALENDAR"

Comment: @miracle173: I mean the value in `NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS` view. aka the session parameter value for `NLS_CALENDAR`.

Comment: You should add this to your question. The NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS shows the session parameter values. These are defined by the environment variables. What do the NLS_INSTANCE_PARAMETERS  and NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS show?

Comment: Maybe you can use a login trigger to set your session parameters.

Comment: What kind of client are you running? Does it run on the same machine as the database instances? Why are  you not able to change the environment settings? Maybe you can describe your system and your problem a little bit more in detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation clearly describes the precedence for NLS settings: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch3globenv.htm#NLSPG188

```
1 (highest) Explicitly set in SQL functions
2           Set by an ALTER SESSION statement
3           Set as an environment variable
4           Specified in the initialization parameter file
5           Default
```

You can choose the first two from these.
A logon trigger can also issue the `ALTER SESSION`, and you don't need to modify the application code for that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SET_NLSCALENDAR_ONLOGIN AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
BEGIN
  IF SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SESSION_USER') = 'SCOTT' THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_CALENDAR=''Thai Buddha''';
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Check setting for SCOTT and other user:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> select value from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_CALENDAR';

VALUE
-----------
Thai Buddha

SQL> select value from nls_database_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_CALENDAR';

VALUE
-----------
GREGORIAN

SQL> conn hr/hr
Connected.
SQL> select value from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_CALENDAR';

VALUE
-----------
GREGORIAN
```

Comment: Would this trigger affect other instances running on the database? I want to do changes to a specific instance only.

Comment: I could clear the doubt I had in mind with this question in StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25602576/does-after-logon-on-database-trigger-execute-on-multiple-database-instances